# Algorithm for a PERT chart in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Greetings,

As part of a school project, I have to create a program to visualize a PERT diagram. Beyond the front-end aspect that I think I can manage, I have some difficulties for the back-end.

NB: Here is a link that explains the PERT diagrams, I did not find a link in English that would use the same graphic representation as the one we are taught, it should be understandable even if badly translated) --> [HERE](https://www.manager-go.com/gestion-de-projet/dossiers-methodes/construire-un-reseau-pert)

I don't see how I can represent the diagram and what it is made of (tasks and milestones). I have already realized the Task class like this:

```java
public class Task {
    
    private char identifier;
    private int duration;
    private Set<Character> antecedents;
    private Set<Character> successors;
    
    // Getters and setters...
    
}
```

NB: I know that using a character as a unique identifier is inconsistent but this is what was requested.

The tasks would be managed by a class, I don't know yet which one (probably a `Chart` class that will contain a collection of Task and Milestone). To come back to the milestones, I'm thinking of modeling them with their own object like this:

```java
public class Milestone {
    
    private int earliestDate;
    private int latestDate;
    private Set<Character> precedingTasks; // Maybe?
    private Set<Character> succeedingTasks; // Maybe?
    
}
```

Now I have to think about the most optimal way to implement all this, what is above is still a sketch. To render the diagram, I have to figure out where the elements are placed and that's where I start to get stuck.

The hypothesis I have put forward for the moment would be the creation of a `Path` class, which would contain in a list, thus ordered, the tasks that compose the path.

I would like to know your opinion or even your help in the implementation (if my idea is still feasible, how to create these paths?). Also, if I know the level of the task in the diagram (which I managed to do), combined with the paths, could it be enough to graphically render this diagram?

Comment: i read your question 5 times, and I'm still not able to understand what's your question...

Comment: Do you really need a Milestone class? If the article you linked to they only talk about Tasks and earliest/latest dates. Why don't you add these two fields to your Task? Then you start with your origin tasks (without antecedents) and calculate the ealiest dates, and the the latest...